# Debugging and understanding "tying the knot" in a monadic context

Tags: haskell, recursion, monads, tying-the-knot

I'm trying to implement an interpreter for a programming language with lazy-binding in Haskell.

I'm using the tying-the-knot pattern to implement the evaluation of expressions. However I found it extremely hard to debug and to reason about. I spent at least 40 working on this. I learned a lot about laziness and tying-the-knot, but I haven't reached a solution yet and some behaviors still puzzle me.

#### Questions

1. Is there a sensible way to debug the knot and figure out what causes it bottom?

   GHC stacktrace (printed when using profiling options) shows which function *inside the knot* triggers a loop. But that's not helpful: I need to understand what makes the knot strict in the knot's definition, and I couldn't find a way to show this.

   It's been really hard to understand why the knot bottoms and I don't think it will be much easier, the next times I have to debug something like this.
2. How should I tie the knot in a monadic context? I learned that a function like `traverse` is strict for most types and this causes the knot to bottom.

   The only solution I can think of, is to remove the knot. That would increase the problem's complexity (every value would need to be re-computed every time), although this issue can be resolved by caching the value in a `STRef`: that's exactly what I would do in a strict language. I would prefer to avoid this solution and take advantage of Haskell's laziness, otherwise what's the point of it?
3. In the code I provide later in this post, why does `evalSt e1` terminate, while `evalSt e2` doesn't? I can't still understand what's the difference.

#### Language's AST

I tried to simplify my AST as much as possible, and this is the most minimal definition I could come up with:

```
data Expr = Int Int | Negate Expr | Id String | Obj (M.Map String Expr)
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

pprint :: Expr -> String
pprint e = case e of
  Int i -> show i
  Negate i -> "(-" ++ pprint i ++ ")"
  Id i -> i
  Obj obj -> "{" ++ intercalate ", "
    [ k ++ ":" ++ pprint v | (k,v) <- M.toList obj ] ++ "}"
```

###### Example programs

Here are a couple of example expressions represented with the AST above:

```
--         expression: {a:{aa1:(-b), aa2:ab, ab:(-b)}, b:3}
-- should evalutae to: {a:{aa1:-3,   aa2:-3, ab:-3  }, b:3}
e1 = Obj $ M.fromList [
  ("a", Obj $ M.fromList [
    ("aa1", Negate $ Id "b"),
    ("aa2", Id "ab"),
    ("ab", Negate $ Id "b")
    ]),
  ("b", Int 3)
  ]

--         expression: {a:{aa:(-ab), ab:b}, b:3}
-- should evaluate to: {a:{aa:-3,    ab:3}, b:3}
e2 = Obj $ M.fromList [
  ("a", Obj $ M.fromList [
    ("aa", Negate $ Id "ab"),
    ("ab", Id "b")
    ]),
  ("b", Int 3)
  ]
```

#### Pure eval function

I have then defined a function to evaluate an expression. This is the most simple definition I could write:

```
type Scope = M.Map String Expr

eval :: Scope -> Expr -> Expr
eval scope expr = case expr of
  Int i -> Int i
  Id str -> case M.lookup str scope of
    Just e  -> e
    Nothing -> error $ str ++ " not in scope"
  Negate aE -> do
    case (eval scope aE) of
      Int i -> Int $ -i
      _   -> error $ "Can only negate ints. Found: " ++ pprint aE
  Obj kvMap -> Obj $
    let resMap = fmap (eval (M.union resMap scope)) kvMap
    in resMap
```

###### Tying the knot

The most interesting part in the `eval` function is the *tying the knot* in the `Obj kvMap` case:

```
let resMap = fmap (eval (M.union resMap scope)) kvMap
in resMap
```

The idea is that in order to compute the expressions in `kvMap`, the identifiers need to be able to access both the values in `scope` and the results of the expressions in `kvMap`. The computed values are `resMap`, and to compute them we use the scope `resMap ⋃ scope`.

###### It works!

This `eval` function works as expected:

```
GHCi> pprint $ eval M.empty e1
"{a:{aa1:-3, aa2:-3, ab:-3}, b:3}"

GHCi> pprint $ eval M.empty e2
"{a:{aa:-3, ab:3}, b:3}"
```

#### Monadic evaluation

The limitation of the `eval` function above, is that it's pure. In some cases I need to evaluate expressions in a monadic context. For instance I may need `IO` to offer non-pure functions to the guest language.

I've implemented dozens of versions of `eval` (both monadic, using `RecursiveDo`, and of various degrees of purity) in an attempt to understand the issues. I'm presenting the two most interesting ones:

###### Passing the scope through a State monad

```
evalSt' :: Expr -> State Scope Expr
evalSt' expr = do
  scope <- get
  case expr of
    Int i -> pure $ Int i
    Id str -> case M.lookup str scope of
      Just e  -> pure e
      Nothing -> error $ str ++ " not in scope"
    Negate aE -> do
      a <- evalSt' aE
      case a of
        Int i -> pure $ Int $ -i
        _     -> error $ "Can only negate ints. Found: " ++ pprint aE
    Obj obj -> mdo
      put $ M.union newScope scope
      newScope <- traverse evalSt' obj
      put scope
      pure $ Obj newScope

evalSt scope expr = evalState (evalSt' expr) scope
```

This function is able to evaluate the program `e1`, but it bottoms (never return) on `e2`:

```
GHCi> pprint $ evalSt M.empty e1
"{a:{aa1:-3, aa2:-3, ab:-3}, b:3}"

GHCi> pprint $ evalSt M.empty e2
"{a:{aa:
```

I still don't understand how it can compute `e1`, since it does contain `Id`s: isn't that program strict on the scope and shouldn't it bottom `evalSt`? Why it doesn't? And what's different in `e2` to cause the function the function to terminate?

###### Evaluating in the IO monad

```
evalM :: Scope -> Expr -> IO Expr
evalM scope expr = case expr of
  Int i -> pure $ Int i
  Id str -> case M.lookup str scope of
    Just e  -> pure e
    Nothing -> error $ str ++ " not in scope"
  Negate aE -> do
    a <- evalM scope aE
    case a of
      Int i -> pure $ Int $ -i
      _     -> error $ "Can only negate ints. Found: " ++ pprint aE
  Obj kvMap -> mdo
    resMap <- traverse (evalM (M.union resMap scope)) kvMap
    pure $ Obj resMap
```

This function always bottoms (never returns) on every program that uses at least one `Id` node. Even just `{a:1, b:a}`.

#### Scroll back to the top for the questions :-)

Comment: I mean, one big reason that we have monads at all is because Haskell is lazy, laziness means side-effects are untenable, and monads introduce an explicit order of evaluation that makes them sane again. But this also removes the principle upon which tying the knot works. Have your cake, or eat it.

Comment: ...Yes, it would _seem_ like `MonadFix` / `RecursiveDo` changes this, but I have my doubts. There's a reason these aren't very widely used. To find out more, one obvious thing to try is to desugar the recursive `do` to the explicit [`mfix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fix.html#v:mfix) that underlies it.

Comment: You're right. `>>=` (and similar/derived functions) are meant exactly to enforce an order. Didn't consider it before. As you're suggesting, a solution may be to implement a semantic similar to `traverse` (but without the guarantee on the actions' order) using `mfix`. I don't know if it's even possible and it's going to be hard for me as I find it difficult to reason about `fix` and related concepts. But will try it!

Comment: To try to make the `IO` issue crisp, suppose you had a `Print` expression which printed its argument and then returned, i.e. `evalIO scope (Print e) = do { v <- evalIO scope e; print v; pure v }`. Now, what order should things print for `{a: print c, b: print 1, c: print b}`? I mean obviously the output will be `111`, but will that be because we evaluated a, which forced c, which forced b (hence the output is in `bca` order), or because we `traverse`d the object in alphabetical order (hence the output is in `abc` order)?

Comment: @DanielWagner: any order would be fine, for `print` and the other `IO` actions. However your comment shows that I haven't thought my language through very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I tie the knot in a monadic context?

Your pure evaluation function relies on there being no evaluation order in the semantics of Haskell, so that thunks get forced only when needed. In contrast, most effects are fundamentally ordered, so there is an incompatibility there.

Some monads are lazier than the others, and for those you can get some result out of making your evaluation function monadic, as you've seen with `evalSt e1`. The two most common lazy monads are `Reader` and lazy `State` (which is the one you get from `Control.Monad.State`, as opposed to `Control.Monad.State.Strict`).

But for other effects, such as `IO`, you must control evaluation order explicitly, and that means implementing the cache for lazy evaluation explicitly (via `STRef` for example), instead of implicitly relying on Haskell's own runtime.

> In the code I provide later in this post, why does evalSt e1 terminate, while evalSt e2 doesn't? I can't still understand what's the difference.

To see what is going wrong, unfold `traverse evalSt' obj` where `obj` is `{aa:(-ab), ab:b}`.

```
traverse evalSt' obj
=
do
  x <- evalSt' (Negate (Id "ab"))
  y <- evalSt' (Id "b")
  pure [("aa", x), ("ab", y)]
=
do
  -- evalSt' (Negate (Id "ab"))
  scope1 <- get  -- unused
  a <- evalSt' (Id "ab")
  x <- case a of
    Int i -> pure $ Int $ -i
    _     -> error ...
  -- evalSt' (Id "b")
  scope2 <- get
  y <- case M.lookup "b" scope2 of
    Just e  -> pure e
    Nothing -> error ...
  pure [("aa", x), ("ab", y)]
```

1. We try to print the object `e2`, that ends up looking at the value of the `"aa"` field, which is `x` in the code above.
2. `x` comes from `case a of ...`, which needs `a`.
3. `a` comes from `evalSt' (Id "ab")`, which needs the field `"ab"`, which is `y` (from the knot tying surrounding the `traverse evalSt' obj` we are looking at).
4. `y` comes from `case M.lookup "b" scope2 of ...`, which needs `scope2`.
5. `scope2` comes from `get`, which gets the output state from the action preceding it, which is evaluating `x`.
6. We are already trying to evaluate `x` (from step 2). Hence there is an infinite loop.

This can be fixed by always restoring the state at the end of `evalSt'` (technically, you only need to do this for `Id` and `Negate`, but might as well do it always):

```
evalSt' e = do
  scope <- get
  v <- case e of ...
  put scope
  pure v
```

Or use `Reader` instead, which gives you the power to update state locally for subcomputations, which is exactly what you need here. You can use `local` to surround `traverse evalSt' obj`:

```
  newScope <- local (const (newScope `M.union` scope)) (traverse evalSt' obj)
```

> Is there a sensible way to debug the knot and figure out what causes it bottom?

I don't have a good answer to this. I'm not familiar with debugging tools in Haskell.

You cannot rely on stack traces because subexpressions may force each other in a rather chaotic order. And there is something interfering with print-debugging (`Debug.Trace`) that I don't understand. (I would add `Debug.Trace.trace (pprint expr) $ do` at the beginning of `evalSt'`, but then the trace doesn't make sense to me because things that should be printed once are replicated many times.)

Comment: I still couldn't quite wrap my head around `traverse evalSt' obj`, but will try to think about it a bit longer; tying the knot messes with my thought process quite a bit. Is it impossible to use `instance MonadFix IO` to implement a working solution without resorting to `ST`?

Comment: There are two ideas in "tying the knot": (1) building cyclic structures (when viewing values as graphs of pointers); (2) delaying computations. `MonadFix` is about (1). To achieve (2) with `IO` with native thunks (instead of an explicit encoding), you would need `unsafePerformIO`.